# pytorch: how to directly find gradient w.r.t. loss

Tags: theano, pytorch, autograd

In theano, it was very easy to get the gradient of some variable w.r.t. a given loss:

```
loss = f(x, w)
dl_dw = tt.grad(loss, wrt=w)
```

I get that pytorch goes by a different paradigm, where you'd do something like:

```
loss = f(x, w)
loss.backwards()
dl_dw = w.grad
```

The thing is I might not want to do a full backwards propagation through the graph - just along the path needed to get to w.

I know you can define Variables with `requires_grad=False` if you don't want to backpropagate through them.  But then you have to decide that at the time of variable-creation (and the `requires_grad=False` property is attached to the variable, rather than the call which gets the gradient, which seems odd).

**My Question is** is there some way to backpropagate *on demand* (i.e. only backpropagate along the path needed to compute `dl_dw`, as you would in theano)?

Comment: I think this would be complicated. Note that you can only set requires_grad for leaf variables. So even if you had a handle to all variables in your graph, you couldn't just switch requires_grad = False or True to only compute the gradients you desire. Also note that only gradients of leaf variables are only ever retained (if you want the ones of intermediate variables, you need a hook). If you're interested in the gradients of leaf variables, you could standardly set all their requires_grad = False and then just set the one to true, that you're interested in before backpropagation.

Comment: I think you are looking for [register_backward_hook](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_backward_hook) function. You can modify gradient directly with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this is reallyy easy.  Just use [torch.autograd.grad](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html#torch.autograd.grad)

Example:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import grad

x = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.random.randn(5, 4)))
w = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.random.randn(4, 3)), requires_grad=True)
y = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.random.randn(5, 3)))
loss = ((x.mm(w) - y)**2).sum()
(d_loss_d_w, ) = grad(loss, w)

assert np.allclose(d_loss_d_w.data.numpy(), (x.transpose(0, 1).mm(x.mm(w)-y)*2).data.numpy())
```

Thanks to JerryLin for answering the question [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/disconnected-gradient-in-pytorch/6341/2).